# Sum consecutive instances of numbers greater than value

Tags: conditional-statements

I have a challenge to sum consequtive numbers in a single row where they are greater than 0.
I'll provide a data sample with 2x possible results A or B
data    0 0 1 3 0 4 2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 3 1 0 8
result A  0 4 0 10 0 1 0 6 0 8
result B  4 10 1 6 8
either result A or B would be acceptable, as 0 have no value in my challange.

I've tried various sumif combinations but i cant get it to sum a group of consecutive numbers greater than 0